# Simplifying the equation to find $m$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, upper-lower-bounds

I have constants $\beta$ and $M$ which are positive numbers such that $\eta\leq \frac{\beta}{128M^4}$. We can rewrite the inequality as $\eta = \frac{\theta\beta}{128M^4}$ where $0 < \theta \leq 1$. Let $C = \frac{1 + 128M^4\eta^2}{(1 + \eta \beta)^2} < 1$, $D =\frac{128M^4\eta^2}{(1 + \eta \beta)^2} < 1$ and $ \alpha = C^m  +  DC\frac{C^m-1}{C-1}$ then $\alpha < 1$ where $m \geq 1$. I am trying to write $m$ in terms of $\theta, \beta, M$ and $\alpha$ but I couldn't find a way to write it.

For $\theta = 1$, we can write $D = C^2 - C^3$, then $\alpha = C^m + C^2 - C^{m + 2}$, but I am not able to solve when $\theta$ is variable.

Comment: Your second last equation should be $D = C - C^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to solve for $m$ in the equation $$ \alpha = C^m  +  DC\frac{C^m-1}{C-1},$$ then you're only a couple of steps away, since this implies $$ \alpha +\frac{DC}{C-1}= C^m  +  DC\frac{C^m}{C-1}=C^m\left(1+\frac{1}{C-1}\right).$$

Comment: Can you please clarify how is $DC = 1$?

Comment: @DushyantSahoo Sorry, it obviously shouldn't be $1.$ That's a slip of hand, and I've made correction.